# How to choose the datastore database to connect

Tags: spring, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I have two datastore databases in GCP "default" and "mydb".
My project credentials was provided by the Google Cloud SDK "gcloud auth application-default login" command and when I run my project it connects to the "default" database. How can I choose to connect to the "mydb"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spring-cloud-gcp/pull/2150/files. I don't know which spring boot release this is in, but you can set your database name with `spring.cloud.gcp.datastore.database-id` .